# Is there any way to force visual studio to show me location of an error in *my* code, instead of pointing to the standard library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a small piece of code that does not compile

Visual Studio shows me this error and points to xhash:

```
Error   C2064   term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xhash   114
```

I know that error is somewhere in my code, probably related to unordered map, so template does not resolve. I'm wondering if there's a way to see which part of my code causes compilation error

Comment: Have you checked the function call **stack backtrace**? You can find what you want along the function call path.

Comment: Usually if you look at the full error you can figure out where in your code it is coming from.

Comment: yeah, instead of looking at the error list window, you should search for that in the output window. Rows before the error should help you to locate the starting point.

Comment: The Error List is a bit rubbish, except for very simple or obvious problems. If you look at the full Output you will find a sequence of messages leading back to your own code. Somewhere around there you will find that what you're trying to use as a hashing function is not a function that takes one argument.

Comment: Maybe you should show us a [mcve]

Comment: @rustyhu: C++ is a compiled language. The function call stack only exists in a running program. This program does not compile, and therefore does not run, so there is no function call stack.

Comment: @MSalters I did not read the question carefully, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

The full build output will have many more lines, in the form `".. Instantiated from here..."`. Typically the last of these lines will point to your faulty code, possibly more if you wrote a template yourself.